# Range of $\sin[x]$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

If $f(x) = \sin [x]$ where $[\cdot]$ is the greatest integer function and $f$ is mapped $f:R\rightarrow R$. Now, since an integer and $\pi$ cannot have a common multiple since $\pi$ is irrational then I think it's range might be $(-1,1)$ or $[-1,1]$. Is one of my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the range of $[x]$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, the range of $f$ is 
$$\{\sin(n)\mid n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
which is a countable set.

But the interval $(-1,1)$ is uncountable, so it can't be the range of $f$.

Also, neither of $-1,1$ is in the range of $f$, since $\sin(t)=\pm{1}$ implies $t$ is an odd integer multiple of $\pi/2$, which must be irrational.

As GEdgar notes in a comment, the range of $f$, though countable, can be shown to be *dense* in $[-1,1].\;$Thus, for any $y \in [-1,1]$, and any $\epsilon > 0$, even if $y$ is not in the range of $f$, there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)-y| < \epsilon$.

In other words, for $y \in [-1,1]$, even if $y$ is not in the range of $f$, you can get outputs from $f$ which are *close* to $y{\,-\,}$arbitrarily close, to within any specified positive tolerance.

Comment: But if we are free to choose the value of [x] from the entire set of integers which extends to to infinities we can can easily choose one value which gives our desired output.

Comment: No. For example, which $x$ would yield $f(x) = 1/2$?

Comment: When I graph the function I see some outputs very close to 1/2, so It might be the case if we provide a very large number, we would get our result.

Comment: Not possible. The solution set for the equation $\sin(t) = 1/2$ is ________?

Comment: Oh now I understand this from the fact that an integer cannot be a multiple of an irrational number...

Comment: More precisely, a _nonzero_ integer can't be a rational multiple of an irrational number.

Answer (score 0):

I think the range of $\sin [x]$ is $\{\sin n | n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and of course, it is subset of $(-1,1)$.

Comment: A countable dense subset.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct in the sense that the range of the function will be dense in the interval $[-1,1]$, but as mentioned above it will also be countable and this not equal to the interval.

Comment: You mean [-1,1]?

Comment: Yep, thanks! Edited appropriately.